# Acer Logo appears twice before Ubuntu finally opens

Tags: boot

I recently installed updates on my newly installed ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I rebooted my PC afterwards and it won't boot. Only shows a message:

```
Failed to open \efi\boot\mmx64.efi -Not found
Failed to load image \efi\boot\mmx64.efi - Not found
Failed to start MokManager: Not found
Something has gone seriously wrong: Import_mok_state() failed
:Not found
```

Then I tried altering boot options to add yet another ubuntu efi boot option and moved it up the list and it boots.
The problem now is that it tries to boot then goes back to acer logo twice before it finally opens. It now takes quite a bit of time to boot. Any ideas?

Comment: Not really. I can boot to ubuntu now. It's just that it's taking longer because it reverts to the acer logo twice first before boot.

Comment: I have windows 10 installed on the same laptop and it doesn't have the same problem.